# Optimizing pairwise subtruction

Tags: python, optimization

I have to compute the pairwise difference of particle's velocities for around 1e6 objects each with approx. 1e4 particles. Right now I am using itertools.combinations to loop over the particles, but just for one object my code takes already more than 30 minutes. I was wondering what else can I do to speed it up to a feasible speed, since parallelising doesn't seem to add much in python. Is cython the way to go?

Here is my code just for one of the objects:

```
def pairwisevel(hist,velj,velk, xj, xk):
    vlos = (velj - velk) 
    if( (xj - xk) < 0.):
        vlos = - vlos
    hist.add_from_value(vlos)


for i in itertools.combinations(np.arange(0,int(particles_per_group[0]),1),2):
    pairwisevel(hist, pvel[i[0]], pvel[i[1]],\
                pcoords[i[0]], pcoords[i[1]])
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want all the combinations of 1e6 and 1e4 points? I.e. on the order of 1e10 pairings? That is going to take a while, no matter what... (Although 30 mins for just one of the points (i.e. just 1e6 or 1e4 pairs) seems definitely too long)

Comment: What exactly is `hist.add_from_value` doing? My guess is that this is the culprit, as that's probably updating all sorts of values in the histogram (?) that only need updating again for the next point. Have you tried collecting the points in a list and updating the histogram with all those points in the end?

Comment: for now I only want the combinations within the same object. And hist is a histogram class, so I only save the number of pairs belonging to a velocity difference bin. In total I have 30 velocity bins, and I thought that would be more efficient than storing all the pairs differences

Comment: How large is one object (How many particles?)  Do you have to use particles_per_group or is your main goal to compute all combinations of pvel's)? What is  hist exactly? Something like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html?

Comment: They have around 1e4 to 1e5 particles. By now I just want to look at the pairwise velocity distributions inside every object to infere the importance of different object characteristics. In the future, I'd like to also look at the correlations of pairwise velocities of particles belonging to different objects. (Thank you for the comments btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your qusition. In this example I calculated the histogramm of one particle object. But if you wan't to do this for all 1e6 groups (1e4*1e4*1e6=1e14) comparisons, this would still take a few days.
In this example I used [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to accomplish the task.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

#From Numba source
#Copyright (c) 2012, Anaconda, Inc.
#All rights reserved.

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def digitize(x, bins, right=False):
    # bins are monotonically-increasing
    n = len(bins)
    lo = 0
    hi = n

    if right:
        if np.isnan(x):
            # Find the first nan (i.e. the last from the end of bins,
            # since there shouldn't be many of them in practice)
            for i in range(n, 0, -1):
                if not np.isnan(bins[i - 1]):
                    return i
            return 0
        while hi > lo:
            mid = (lo + hi) >> 1
            if bins[mid] < x:
                # mid is too low => narrow to upper bins
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                # mid is too high, or is a NaN => narrow to lower bins
                hi = mid
    else:
        if np.isnan(x):
            # NaNs end up in the last bin
            return n
        while hi > lo:
            mid = (lo + hi) >> 1
            if bins[mid] <= x:
                # mid is too low => narrow to upper bins
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                # mid is too high, or is a NaN => narrow to lower bins
                hi = mid

    return lo

#Variant_1
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def bincount_comb_1(pvel,pcoords,bins):
  vlos_binned=np.zeros(bins.shape[0]+1,dtype=np.uint64)
  for i in nb.prange(pvel.shape[0]):
    for j in range(pvel.shape[0]):
      if( (pcoords[i] - pcoords[j]) < 0.):
        vlos = 0.
      else:
        vlos = (pvel[i] - pvel[j])

      dig_vlos=digitize(vlos, bins, right=False)
      vlos_binned[dig_vlos]+=1
  return vlos_binned

#Variant_2
#Is this also working?
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def bincount_comb_2(pvel,pcoords,bins):
  vlos_binned=np.zeros(bins.shape[0]+1,dtype=np.uint64)
  for i in nb.prange(pvel.shape[0]):
    for j in range(pvel.shape[0]):
      #only particles which fulfill this condition are counted?
      if( (pcoords[i] - pcoords[j]) < 0.):
        vlos = (pvel[i] - pvel[j])
        dig_vlos=digitize(vlos, bins, right=False)
        vlos_binned[dig_vlos]+=1
  return vlos_binned

#Variant_3
#Only counting once
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def bincount_comb_3(pvel,pcoords,bins):
  vlos_binned=np.zeros(bins.shape[0]+1,dtype=np.uint64)
  for i in nb.prange(pvel.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i,pvel.shape[0]):
      #only particles, where this condition is met are counted?
      if( (pcoords[i] - pcoords[j]) < 0.):
        vlos = (pvel[i] - pvel[j])
        dig_vlos=digitize(vlos, bins, right=False)
        vlos_binned[dig_vlos]+=1
  return vlos_binned


#Create some data to test
bins=np.arange(2,32)
pvel=np.random.rand(10_000)*35
pcoords=np.random.rand(10_000)*35

#first call has compilation overhead, we don't measure this
res_1=bincount_comb_1(pvel,pcoords,bins)
res_2=bincount_comb_2(pvel,pcoords,bins)

t1=time.time()
res=bincount_comb_1(pvel,pcoords,bins)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
res=bincount_comb_2(pvel,pcoords,bins)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
res=bincount_comb_3(pvel,pcoords,bins)
print(time.time()-t1)
```

**Performance**

```
#Variant_1: 0.5s 5.78d for 1e6 groups of points
#Variant_2: 0.3s 3.25d for 1e6 groups of points
#Variant_3: 0.22s 2.54d for 1e6 groups of points
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had never heard about it, but this numba is amazing :D